# Stuck inside Promise

Tags: node.js, dictionary, promise

Using native node promises. Here is my code:

```
    (req, res) => 
    requestp('https://swapi.co/api/planets')
    .then((planets) => Promise.all(planets.results.map(planet => {
        var residents = planet.residents.map(requestp(r))
        return {
            planetName: planet.name,
            residents: Promise.all(residents).then((r) => r.name)
        }
    }))
    .then((planets) => res.json(planets.map(p => {
        let obj = {}
        return res.json(obj[p.planetName] = p.residents);
    }))))
    .catch((err) => res.status(400).send(err))
```

I am trying to return an array of objects that look like this:

`{ Alderaan: ["nameofResident1","nameofResident2"]}`

I seem to be getting stuck in `planet.residents.map()` part of my code though.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `{}[p.planetName] = p.residents` is a very odd thing to be doing.

Comment: I know. But this is irrelevant to the question. its so i can set the planet name as the key in the object.

Comment: That returns `[ p.residents ]` for me though which I don't think is what you intended.

Comment: When calling `all` it's expecting an array of promises, but that's not what you're giving it. You're supplying an array of objects which have a property with promises in them, but `Promise.all` won't look there.

Comment: Made the changes.

Comment: `x[y] = z` yields `z`, so be careful here. Sometimes too much minifying causes completely different results.

Comment: which "all" are you talking about? The first, or second?

Comment: Once `planets` are obtained each planet has the property `planet.residents`. Do you really need an inner call to `requestp()` to obtain residents' names? Are they not obtainable synchronously?

Comment: the `planet.residents` is a list of urls.

Comment: `Promise.all()` resolves to an array of results.

Comment: I am aware, I am not sure what you are saying here.

Comment: `r.name` is undefined.

Comment: Why? requestp returns a promise.

Comment: Because it is an array.

Comment: In your statement `Promise.all(residents).then((r) => r.name)` r is an array. `r.name` is undefined, so your promise resolves to undefined. You need to map the array of objects to an array of their names.

Answer (score 0):

If you break down the inner workings to some functions, not only does it make it easier to write, it makes it easier to read

In the following, to make it executable, I called the main function `doit` -

I also added a `requestp` function, which uses `fetch` - so the snippet wont work unless you use a modern browser (no Internet Explorer allowed here)

run the snippet, you should see the result you are looking for

```js
// you wont need this function
var requestp = (url) => fetch(url).then(response=>response.json());

// code starts here
var getResidentName = (url) => requestp(url).then((resident) => resident.name);
var getAllResidentNames = (residents) => Promise.all(residents.map(r => getResidentName(r)));
var processPlanet = (planet) => getAllResidentNames(planet.residents).then((residents) => ({[planet.name]: residents}));
var processPlanets = (planets) => Promise.all(planets.results.map(planet => processPlanet(planet)));

// slight change so it can run in the snippet, ignore the var doit = for your code
var doit = (req, res) => 
    requestp('https://swapi.co/api/planets')
    .then(processPlanets)
    .catch((err) => res.status(400).send(err));


// doit and log the result as a JSON string
doit().then(result => console.log(JSON.stringify(result)));
```

The code you would use from above can also be written

```
(req, res) => {
    var getResidentName = (url) => requestp(url).then((resident) => resident.name);
    var getAllResidentNames = (residents) => Promise.all(residents.map(r => getResidentName(r)));
    var processPlanet = (planet) => getAllResidentNames(planet.residents).then((residents) => ({[planet.name]: residents}));
    var processPlanets = (planets) => Promise.all(planets.results.map(planet => processPlanet(planet)));

    return requestp('https://swapi.co/api/planets')
        .then(processPlanets)
        .catch((err) => res.status(400).send(err));
}
```

That way all the "support" functions are not polluting the global namespace

After you have it working, you can, if you must, refactor the code into one monolithic block quite easily